# How can I stop a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view from stretching when I rotate the ipad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a number of `UIBarButtonItem`s in my navigation bar for each view controller. The last one on the right is an item with a custom view, since the number on the item is meant to update as you add or remove items from your cart.

When I add the items to the view controller's `navigationItem`, initially everything looks good. however when I rotate the ipad, the button stretches (if it started in portrait) or it shrinks (if it started in landscape) Example images to illustrate:

[image: Expected appearance in portrait]
[image: Stretched out appearance in landscape]

I've tried setting the width of the item to 44 (the size of the custom uibutton as it is in the xib i've designed it in), setting width constraints on the custom view in autolayout, etc, but that doesn't work. How can I force the navigation item to stay a fixed size for custom views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this issue. If I override `setFrame:` in my uibutton subclass like so:

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    frame.size.width = 44;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

then it lays out correctly. Seems like an annoying hack/workaround, but it works!